# Processing HTML Quiz Form Through Django/jQuery backend

Tags: jquery, django, sqlite

I have a radio button form that is acting as a multiple choice quiz in my template. I need to check that the answer chosen is the correct answer and then update the score attribute in the model by 1. I know now how to check the button values in jQuery, but I'm not sure how to process it through Djanog.

```
    {% extends "mainpage/base.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Multiple Choice</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#quiz').on('change', function(){
        if($('input[name=optradio]:checked').val() == "{{correctAnswer}}"){

          // var $score = '{{score}}';
          // var s = $score.val();
          // s++;
          // alert(s);
          // alert('youre correct');
          //if the user choses the right button and submits quiz, then show them their score
        }
        //  alert('correct');
      })
    })

    // })
    </script>
    </head>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <html>
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <div class="container">
       <form method="GET" class="QuestionForm" id="quiz">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="A" value="{{answerA}}">{{answerA}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="B" value="{{answerB}}">{{answerB}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="C" value="{{answerC}}">{{answerC}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="D" value="{{answerD}}">{{answerD}}</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </html>
    {% endblock %}


def results(request):
    # show results of quiz to user
    return redirect('https://www.google.de/')

def view_takeQuiz(request,quizID):
    try:
        quiz = Quiz.objects.get(quizID=quizID)
        context = {'title': quiz.title, 'answerA': quiz.answerA, 'answerB': quiz.answerB,
        'answerC': quiz.answerC,'answerD': quiz.answerD,
        'correctAnswer': quiz.correctAnswer, 'score':quiz.score}
        return render(request, 'multipleChoice/takeQuiz.html', context)

    except:
        return render(request, 'multipleChoice/quiz.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where "Ajax" comes into the picture.

> With Ajax, Web applications can send data to and retrieve from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. By decoupling the data interchange layer from the presentation layer, Ajax allows for Web pages, and by extension Web applications, to change content dynamically without the need to reload the entire page

So what Ajax does, is that it sends a request from the Javascript (client) to the server, and return a response, without having to refresh the page that the client is on.

jQuery already got multiple build in HTTP Request functions that you can use to do Ajax request to the backend. The most common used ones are:

- $.ajax() [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- $.post() [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- $.get() [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

In your case you want to submit form data to the backend. Therefore I suggest you to use `$.post()` to do this.

For example:

```
// When the form is submitted...
$('form#quiz').on('submit', function(e) {
    // ... Stop it from refreshing the page.
    e.preventDefault();

    //... then send the data to the backend server
    $.post('/myurl/handlepost/', {data: $(this).serialize()}, function(response){
        // This is where you handle a successful call.
        // The `response` var contains the data output from
        // the backend.
    });
});
```

Notice that you have to replace the URL I used to the actual URL to one of your views in Django that handles the request. Also notice that your current view (`view_takeQuiz()`) only handles a `GET` request. Not a `POST` request.

Lastly! Django uses a csrf-token to make sure that the request should be allowed. In your case you include the CSRF token outside of the actual form. You should move the `{% csrf_token %}` into the `<form>...</form>`.

Comment: Ok, but I don't really understand the code snippet you posted

Comment: If you don't understand the code snippet then I think you have jumped into the deep end of the pool a bit too early. Perhaps you should go back and learn more about Javascript and jQuery before you continue building your website.

I suggest you to perhaps take a class at http://teamtreehouse.com/

Comment: Even if you feel that you perhaps don't understand the code snippet, if you think that my answer was correct to your question, I kindly ask you to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your models using django, you can do the following.

Firstly, change your form method to post.

Then add an action attribute to your form:
    action="{ url 'multipleChoice:view_takeQuiz' quiz.id}"

This specifies where the form data gets sent, and it passes along the quiz id as a variable when the form is submitted.

Next you have to link that url to the view method which you want to handle the form data. This is done by adding the following to your urls.py:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    # other urls
        url(r'^result/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.view_takeQuiz , name='view_takeQuiz'),
   ]
```

The (?P[0-9]+) can be any interger value, and it is this which stores your quiz id number, which was passed from your form in the action attribute, This is then stored in the quizID variable passed to your view_takeQuiz method

Then in your view method, you can process the data similar to what you have in your question, except use request.POST instead of GET

Comment: I'll try it out and get back to you and mark as correct if it runs. Thanks!

Comment: I get a page not found error when I submit. I believe the error is in my urls.py file

Comment: Whats the name of your django app? I assumed it was multipleChoice, but if not then replace multipleChoice in your action attribute to your app name. Your app name is the name of the folder which contains views.py

Comment: Yes, that is the name of my app. I want to , upon submit, redirect to a results page which will present the updated score attribute. When I submit right now, it gives me the can't be found. I'll post the snippet

Comment: url(r'^multipleChoice/(?P<quizID>[\w]+)/$', views.results, name='results')

Comment: def results(request):
    try:
        quiz = Quiz.objects.get(quizID=quizID)
        context = {'title': quiz.title, 'answerA': quiz.answerA, 'answerB': quiz.answerB,
        'answerC': quiz.answerC,'answerD': quiz.answerD,
        'correctAnswer': quiz.correctAnswer, 'score':quiz.score}
        return render(request, 'multipleChoice/takeQuiz.html', context)
        if request.method == 'POST':
           quiz.score += 1
           quiz.save()
           return redirect('https://google.de')
    except:
        return render(request, 'multipleChoice/quiz.html', {})

Comment: Hard to debug in the comments section, but here is an tutorial which may help you figure out where you are going wrong. It is similar to what you are trying to do,  it takes in data from a form and stores it in a model, it also makes uses of Django forms, which is better than hard coding the forms in your template: https://www.simplifiedpython.net/django-save-form-data-to-database/